# count all rows in excel that contain some string subset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

not even sure if this is possible in excel .

i want to compare all the rows in the column and get the count of them if the string contains "the"

so i know i can do this
    =count(B0:B99)

is there a way to do B0- BN ? the count

```
  (~df.col3.str.contains('u|z')).sum()  found this trying to make this work so i know its possible now.
```

now can i only count them if b0- bn contain the string "the" . lets assume all the rows contain strings

my backup plan is exporting the data and writing a ruby script to do it but i feel like i should be

note everything is in column B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("the ",B:B),0)<>0,1,0))
```

enter this as array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in formula bar.

Result should look like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("the ",B:B),0)<>0,1,0))}
```

Comment: You might still miscount if B2 contains just "the" [not counted] or B3 contains "scythe bearer" [counted]. This non-array version should count all cells that contain "the" as a separate word `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" the "," "&B:B&" "))+0)` - there can still be miscounting if you have punctuation but that can be eliminated by adding SUBSTITUTE functions to remove commas etc.

Answer (score 1):

This will count all cells which contain string "the" in your column:

`=COUNTIF(B1:B99,"*the*")`

Comment: This works, though it will also find words like "theory" that have "the" as a substring. Also, can generalize to B:B instead of B1:B99 to do B0-BN as OP asks...

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra column (D) with formulas similar to `=IFERROR(SEARCH("the",C1),0)` in each cell where Column C contains the text you want to search, and add a summary formula `=SUMIF(D1:D100,">0",B1:B100)` to a single cell where Column B contains the numbers you want to sum.